Swagger UI issue in deployed aws server built using springboot
I have been working on springboot
I have the following dependencies:
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>

I am running my application in AWS Lambda behind an Api Gateway. The apis work great both in my local and in the cloud.
I decided to add a swagger-ui to the project and added following dependency:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

In my local I can get the swagger ui perfectly but in the cloud, the swagger ui page shows only a blank page. When I checked the console logs, it says:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at swagger-ui-bundle.js:2:867116) swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:2:138206) swagger-initializer.js:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined at window.onload (swagger-initializer.js:5:3)
window.onload @ swagger-initializer.js:5
I checked the swagger-ui-bundle.js:2:867116 and
It looks like the file is correct up to some point and then it looks like a character encoding issue: 69389:(e,t,n)=>{var r=n(18674)({Ã€:"A",Ã:"A",Ã‚:"A",Ãƒ:"A
Is there a fix for this?
Thanks in advance
